# How did John McClane escape his bonds?

Tags: a-good-day-to-die-hard

I may have missed how this happened, but in the scene with John and Jack captured in the ballroom, we see Jack take his knife and cut through his wrist ties, but I have no idea how John got free.

Can somebody fill me in?

Comment: because he's Mcclane?  haha  i think it had something to do either with the guard accidentally breaking him out or just a cut of getting a knife as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a continuity error (or movie-plot-magic).
It's even listed on [moviemistakes](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film9550) (along with 23 other errors).

It's plausible that the producers cut the bit where Jack passes the knife to John, the scene may have originally been longer.
However, There's roughly 6 seconds between seeing Jack trying to free himself and a freed John lunging for one of the guards.
Though the chances of both of them freeing themselves in that timeframe (& passing the knife from Jack to John, unnoticed) while surrounded by armed men are not good.

Comment: Cool - so it wasn't just a combination of the terrible shaky-cam and and my advanced years then.